# Can I get colocation data in underground area (like as subway, parking lot, etc..)?

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I set up cllocation manage by following code. It work in the open area. However, my phone can't received any datas (all datas was 0) after I went into subway or underground area.

What should I do if I want to make app work in subway as well? Is it necessary to integrate startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges/startMonitoringForRegion method with standard location update method together? If so, how do I make it?

In init method

```
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.delegate=self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

In cllocation delegate method

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"%@",newLocation);
    NSDate*eventDate=newLocation.timestamp;
    NSTimeInterval howRecent=abs([eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);

    if ((newLocation.coordinate.latitude != oldLocation.coordinate.latitude)&&(newLocation.coordinate.longitude != oldLocation.coordinate.longitude)) {
        locationChanged=YES;

    }else{
        locationChanged=NO;
    }

     if ((howRecent <5.0)&&
        ((newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<(oldLocation.horizontalAccuracy -10.0))||
         (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<50.0)||
         ((newLocation.horizontalAccuracy<=120)&& locationChanged))) {
            self.myLocation=[newLocation copy];

           // NSLog(@"mylocation==%@",[self.myLocation description]);

        }

    //location info draw from plist
    CLLocation *targetLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Target_LAT longitude:Target_LONG];

     double distance = [self.myLocation distanceFromLocation:targetLocation]/1000;
     NSString*distString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f km",distance];

     [delegate getLocationUpdate:self.myLocation distanceUpdate:distString];
       //In this testing app, I use delegate to take cllocation data. Then those datas display in view controller.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If it doesn't work in a subway, thats because your phone can't read the GPS satellites.  If you want you can save the last location and notify the user that the location has been lost or something.

Comment: @WolfLink in document, startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or startMonitoringForRegion method look like that it is able to detect cllocation data through wifi or cellular signal. So I'm thinking about integrate that 2 methods with standard location update, in order to get cllocation data continuously. Is it possible?

Comment: The `CLLocationManager` will use wifi or cellular when wifi is unavailable no matter what you do.  If those aren't working either, then maybe you don't have wifi or cellular either.

Comment: Another possibility is that when you ask for the location, it can take a little time for the `CLLocationManager` to actually come up with your location.  Try checking the `CLLocationManager` again after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location data for a mobile device In a Couple of ways. Device based (GPS, AGPS, WIFI etc when you are in GPS line of sight ) or CELLID based (off device - mobile number based whether you are in GPS line of sight or not as this is cellID based)..as you know your app can also get location information underground(out of line of sight) if it is using cellID  Keep in mind that in underground situations if there is no wifi then you are out of luck.
I would love to say that you should use geoloqal.com (me) to locate mobile devices via cellID or GPS - however, unfortunately, in the subway we still will not be able to help you.